# Supplying api key in HttpClient's headers not working

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get data from https://ndb.nal.usda.gov, basing on instructions provided here https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/apilist/API-FOOD-REPORT.md

I'm using HttpClient as follows, but can't seem to be able to pass the api_key correctly. Shouldn't I be adding it to headers? I tried

```
public static async Task<string> DownloadItemData(string itemName)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpContent requestContent =
                new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", "myKey"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ndbno", "01009"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type", "f")
                });

            requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports", requestContent);

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                // Write the output.
                string result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return result;
            }
        }
```

But all I'm getting is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "API_KEY_MISSING",
    "message": "No api_key was supplied. Get one at http://api.nal.usda.gov"
  }
}
```

I also tried this, but with the same result:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("api_key", "myKey");
```

Any ideas how to pass the api_key correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In [the example they give](http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno=01009&type=f&format=json&api_key=DEMO_KEY) the values are in the querystring.

Comment: Yes, indeed I messed up the whole concept. Thank you, that answers my question